# Spring.NET WebServiceExporter and MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, spring.net

I'm trying to get a simple Spring.NET webservice working with MVC3 but although there are no errors, and I can see from the logs that Spring is deploying it, I can't htt the correct URL for my web service at all.

I *think* I've followed the example (that comes with Spring.NET) correctly. Mine differs in that I'm not doing any AOP weaving on my service. As far as I can tell, it should work.... but doesn't.

Here's my service class (very basic)

```cs
public interface IHelloService
{
    string SayHello();
}

public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public String SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And here's my config

```xml
<!-- Web services -->
<object id="HelloService" type="Munch.Service.Web.HelloService, Munch.Service"/>

<!-- Exports contact service (weaved or not) as a web service. -->
<object id="HelloWebService" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web">
  <property name="TargetName" value="HelloService"/>
  <property name="Namespace" value="http://Munch.Service.Web/HelloService"/>
  <property name="Description" value="Hello Web Services"/>
  <property name="TypeAttributes">
    <list>
      <object type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute, System.Web.Extensions"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</object>
```

I would expect to be able to access my web service at something like http://localhost:8080/Munch/HelloWebService.asmx but no joy with any of the variations I have tried. Is there a way to find out what web services have been deployed (some debug page perhaps)?

The example that comes with Spring does actually work(!) so I know it's possible to get a working Spring WS on my machine, I just can't see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Does Spring.NET webservices even work with MVC3/.NET4? I've spent all night on this again and still can't even get the simplest examples to work :(

Comment: Hmmm, well after looking at the SpringAir example app, I can see straight away that the WebServiceExporter definition has an additional 'name' attribute name="/BookingAgent.asmx". That looks like it might be useful. There's also a 'Name' prooperty on it too, which I don't have. I'll give that a try tonight...

Comment: The example in SpringAir also works. I have no idea whats going on. How can I see whether my web service (any web service) has been deployed in my app? All I can do at the moment is try to guess the name and then I get 404 errors...

Comment: Don't forget to register the HTTP handler for *.asmx

Comment: Thanks bbaia, I've done that I think. I don't know if I'm using IIS7  or not (whatever comes with VS2010 I guess) so I've tried both ways. I've currently got it as: <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>

Comment: I wonder... Since WebServiceHandlerFactory is registered for the path *.asmx, when I request a .asmx URL should I see something in the logs saying WebServiceHandlerFactory is trying to process that request? Because I'm not seeing anything like that. If I should be, maybe my config IS wrong somehow. Can anyone tell me if that's the case?

Comment: Oh man, if I debug the WebServiceExporter, if I look at the DeclaringMethod property of the 'proxyType' variable it uses, I get base {System.SystemException} = {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}. Could this be my problem? Something wrong with the interface my web service implements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use to publish your `HelloService` in the spring.net `Spring.Mvc3QuickStart` that ships with spring.net 1.3.2.

These were the things I had to do to get it to work:

1. Add the service configuration to the spring.net mvc context
2. Add all asmx resources to `routes.IgnoreRoute`
3. Add the `Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceHandlerFactory` from `Spring.Web`, as bbaia had commented on your question

I suspect you've forgotten to add all asmx resources to `routes.IgnoreRoute`.

*Step-by-step*

Start with the Spring.Mvc3QuickStart example application that ships with Spring.Net 1.3.2.

Reference the project that contains the `HelloService` class from your question.

Add a file `~/Config/services.xml` to the project, containing your service configuration:

```xml
<object id="HelloService" type="Munch.Service.Web.HelloService, Munch.Service"/>

<object id="HelloWebService" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web">
  <property name="TargetName" value="HelloService"/>
  <property name="Namespace" value="http://Munch.Service.Web/HelloService"/>
  <property name="Description" value="Hello Web Services"/>
  <property name="TypeAttributes">
    <list>
      <object type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute, System.Web.Extensions"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</object>
```

In Global.asax, add

```cs
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```

to [`RegisterRoutes`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx). This will tell the asp.net mvc handler to leave requests to asmx resources alone.

In web.config, add the following http handler:

```xml
<system.web>
  <!-- ... -->
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceHandlerFactory, Spring.Web" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <!-- ... -->
```

In web.config, add your service configuration to the spring context:

```xml
<spring>
  <context>
    <resource uri="file://~/Config/controllers.xml" />
    <resource uri="file://~/Config/services.xml" />
  </context>
</spring>
```

When you run the application from Visual Studio, you should be able to view the service at http://localhost:12345/HelloWebService.asmx (replace 12345 with you dev port).

*Notes*

I'm unfamiliar with asp.net-mvc, so there might be better ways to configure it than I've suggested.

Comment: Oooohhhh, that does sound like something I have forgotten actually. Thanks for looking at my problem. As soon as I get home I'll be googling that (since I'm not really sure what the 'routes' stuff is), and looking at the Quickstart app to see the differences. Thanks Marijn, will be extremely happy if I can get this to finally work.

Comment: Marijn, thanks a million, it works! You were indeed correct, I just needed to add the 'ignoreRoutes' to my global.asax. The simplest thing but I spent 3 nights trying to figure it out, arghhhh. You get the bounty! :)

Comment: I've added my own version here (same as yours Marijn really) but more examples can't hurt! http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?9483-WebServiceExporter-debugging&p=25635#post25635